# JS сравнить два числа

Tags: javascript, сравнение, числа

Не пойму почему 5000 меньше 20000

```
if(5000 > 20000) {
    alert("Меньше");
}
```

Ноли что ли убирает?

Поборол с помощью parseInt
Но почему первый вариант не срабатывает так и не понял...

ПС.
Т.е. не понятно почему JS считает что число 5000 больше 200000 (лож)

А число 5000 меньше 60000 (что правильно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Поборол с помощью parseInt Но почему первый вариант не срабатывает так и не понял...
```

Потому что вы сравниваете строки (либо одна из переменных у вас строка) http://jsfiddle.net/56k2r/2/

Comment: в `parseInt()` не забудьте дописать второй параметр `10` (систему счисления) — а то в некоторых случаях результаты окажутся непредсказуемы - например, если дописан ноль в начале:

    alert ( 010 < 10); 
    // true:   010 восьмеричной системы == 8 десятичной

Comment: > alert ( 010 < 10); 
> // true:   010 восьмеричной системы == 8 десятичной

010 меньше 10 потому что 0 < 1 идет сравнение слева направо, по строке

Answer (score 0):

Знак ">" означает "больше", т.е

```
если(5000 больше 20000) {
   alert("Меньше");
}
```

Comment: Я в курсе что он означает "больше"
Я сравниваю два числа, если второе число меньше, то вывожу сообщение "меньше"
Если второе число больше, то продолжаю выполнение скрипта.
Конструкция выше не работает должным образом, но если ввести скажем так

    if(5000 > 60000) {
        alert("Меньше");
    }

В данном случае все правильно.

Поборол так


    if(parseInt(5000) > parseInt(20000)) {
        alert("Меньше");
    }
При таком варианте сообщение "Меньше" не выводиться, т.е. все правильно работает.

Comment: @webphp у меня во всех случаях ничего не показывает. Так и должно быть. Chrome 34 linux mint 16

Comment: странно, у меня в случае 


    // req.body.price = 5000
    // req.body.buyout = 20000

    if(req.body.buyout) if(req.body.price > req.body.buyout) return callback("buyout меньше price");

Получаю в консоле сообщение что buyout меньше price

xD

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/YoSgO9A.png

Какой у вас браузер?